# Python ExcelWriter How to write data to different columns in different sheets

Tags: python, pandas.excelwriter

I want to append the vectors to different excel columns at different sheets. The code is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

for i in range(3):
    for j in range(2):
        with pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', mode='a+', engine='openpyxl') as writer:
            x = np.random.rand(10, 1)
            x = pd.DataFrame(x)
            x.to_excel(writer,
                       sheet_name=f'Sheet{j}',
                       startcol=i,
                       index=False,
                       header=False)
            writer.save()
```

The outer `i` loop determines the index of column to insert, and the inner `j` loop determines which sheet to write to. But this doesn't work. Only Sheet1 is shown and only one column has data inserted. It seems in every loop a new sheet is created regardless the sheet with the same name exists.
How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you would need to move your `with pd.ExcelWriter` before the loop otherwise it will leave only the last instance in the excel.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

with pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', mode='a+', engine='openpyxl') as writer:
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(2):
                x = np.random.rand(10, 1)
                x = pd.DataFrame(x)
                x.to_excel(writer,
                           sheet_name=f'Sheet{j}',
                           startcol=i,
                           index=False,
                           header=False)
    #writer.save()
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It works. Unfortunately, this is not what I need. In my real code, there are not only x, but also y and z. All of them are calculated in the loops. What I need is to save them into each individual excel file at the end of each iteration of the inside loop.

Comment: make sense, I would suggest that you build a data frame that is very close to the worksheet, and once all the data frames are built, then at the final step write them to excel, in this way will save i/o operation too. I would recommend that you revise your question or put new  one which is close to problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Thank @simpleApp. I thought about this option before. But this code execution takes a long time to complete. I want to check the saved data during the process to see if it's worthy to wait for the completion.